# WebView на Андроид

Tags: java, android, activity, webview, android-intent

Столкнулся с такой проблемой:
Написал приложение под Андроид, с несколькими экранами, один из которых `WebView`. После определенного действия на первом экране, должен открыться второй экран (webview) и открыть странницу, которую мы задаем на первом экране. Спустя 15 секунд приложение должно вернуться на первый экран.

По большому счету это все работает (правда подвисает при ожидании этих 15 секунд), но интересует вопрос:
При переходе на экран с `WebView` приложение запрашивает: какой браузер запустить? и на выбор несколько вариантов, в том числе и экран с `WebView`.

Можно ли прописать программно, чтобы автоматически запускался `WebView`, без удаления других браузеров с телефона и без установки его по умолчанию?

Comment: "должен открыться второй экран (webview)" - это значит "запуск вашей Activity, в разметке которой есть WebView, чрез Intent? В общем нам надо код, коим вы вызываете эту вашу Activity вторую.

Comment: startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(UrlServer)));

Comment: а возвращаюсь на первый Activity через startActivity(new Intent(WebViewActivity.this, MainActivity.class));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваша проблема в том, что вы предлагаете андроиду открыть ссылку одним из известных ему способов, вместо открытия вашей активити.

Вам надо открывать активити с WebView тем же способом что вы открываете первую активити и передать ссылку через интент коим вы её запускаете.

P.S. Код смогу чрез часа полтора только добавить. Из приложения не кдобно.

Comment: спасибо за комментарий. Действительно, переписал код и вроде не спрашивает:Intent intent3 = new Intent("learn2crack.jsonparsing.Browser");
   intent3.setData(Uri.parse(UrlServer));
   startActivity(intent3);

Comment: Если ответ решил проблему, то слева от него есть галочка "отметить верным" =)